# Count instances of combination of columns in spark dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a spark data frame in scala called df with two columns, say a and b. Column a contains letters and column b contains numbers giving the below.

```
   a   b
----------
   g   0
   f   0
   g   0
   f   1
```

I can get the distinct rows using

```
val dfDistinct=df.select("a","b").distinct
```

which gives the following:

```
   a  b
----------
   g   0
   f   0
   f   1
```

I want to add another column with the number of times these distinct combinations occurs in the first dataframe so I'd end up with

```
a  b  count
  ----------
  g  0   2
  f  0   1
  f  1   1
```

I don't mind if that modifies the original command or I have a separate operation on dfDistinct giving another data frame.

Any advice greatly appreciated and I apologise for the trivial nature of this question but I'm not the most experienced with this kind of operation in scala or spark.

Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply aggregate and count:

```
df.groupBy($"a", $"b").count
```

or a little bit more verbose:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, lit}

df.groupBy($"a", $"b").agg(count(lit(1)).alias("cnt"))
```

Both are equivalent to a raw SQL aggregation:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT a, b, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM df GROUP BY a, b")
```

Comment: Its always simple when you know it but I don't find it trivial to get the information. Am I missing a resource? Thank you, by the way. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I don't know :) Maybe [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)?

Comment: Thanks again. They have changed the behaviour of that in 5.1! A lesson to read the changes. Accepted the answer and tried to upvote but don't have the rep!

Answer (score 4):

Also see Cross Tabulation

```
val g="g"
val f = "f"
val df = Seq(
  (g, "0"),
  (f, "0"),
  (g, "0"),
  (f, "1")
).toDF("a", "b")
val res = df.stat.crosstab("a","b")
res.show

+---+---+---+
|a_b|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+
|  g|  2|  0|
|  f|  1|  1|
```